# How to use TypeScript interface overloads on an Object Method

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to conditionally return either KML or GeoJSON (string and object types respectively), and I'm wondering how to assign a function like that through an interface on an Object method.

Say the object is

```
const api = {
  getGeometry(url, format) {
    return fetch(`${url}?format=${format}`)
  }
}
```

With an interface like this:

```
interface GeometryRequest {
  (url: string, format: 'kml'): Promise<string>
  (url: string, format: 'geojson'): Promise<GeoJSON.FeatureCollection<any>>
}
```

So I can get that to work as a plain function:

```
const geometryRequest: GeometryRequest = (url, format) => {
  return fetch(`${url}?format=${format}`)
}
```

**I'm just wondering how I can assign a type to an object method in a similar way.**

Here are a couple of methods I tried:

`getGeometry<GeometryRequest>`

`getGeometry: GeometryRequest`

Neither are proper syntax.

I've also added a simpler version of the same problem on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(a%3A%20string)%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(a%3A%20number)%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b(c)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20(c)%20%3D%3D%3D%20'string')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20parseInt(c)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20String(c)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20output%20%3D%20a.b(123)).  In the playground `output`'s type is: `const output: string | number`.  But it should be able to tell the type from the overloaded functions in the interface somehow.

Any help on this syntax problem would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Are you sure the playground link is the correct one? Also it is not clear to me what you want to accomplish. Could you post a snipet with what specifically does not work?

Comment: Shoot, I grabbed the wrong URL and lost it @TitianCernicova-Dragomir

Comment: Fixed. @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function expressions can't specify multiple overloads. We can simulate the effect in one of several ways

Use a type assertion to specify the public signatures of the function

```
const a = {
    b: function(c) {
        if (typeof (c) === 'string') {
            return parseInt(c)
        }
        return String(c)
    } as {
        (a: string): number
        (a: number): string
    }
}
```

Use conditional types to decide the return type based on the input type, although this will cause issues with the implementation when returning a value (the  comp will not let you assign a value because it can't determine it to be safe)

```
const a = {

    b<T extends string|number>(c : T ):T extends string ?number: string {
        if (typeof (c) === 'string') {
            return parseInt(c) as any
        }
        return String(c) as any
    }
}
```

Use a function declaration inside a self executing function and return the declared function

```
const a = {
    b: (function () {
        function b(a: string): number
        function b(a: number): string
        function b(c) {
            if (typeof (c) === 'string') {
                return parseInt(c)
            }
            return String(c)
        }
        return b;
    })()
}
```

Comment: Your first option is extremely preferable.  In my TS Playground link, I simply added `as Test` to the end of the function (also redefining it as `b: function(c) {`. Thanks!